# Running terraria in python

Tags: python

Ok so first things first is the discord bot that I am running on my discord server that will be pulling commands through discord and onto the terraria server! That is the idea!
code for starting the server in the bot's code:

```
def run_terraria_server():
    global proc
    proc = run_terraria.terraria_exe()
```

this is the method that I use to start the server of which the code looks like this :

```
class terraria_exe:
def __init__(self):
    bat_location = r'F:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Terraria'
    Popen('TerrariaServer.exe -steam -lobby friends -config serverconfig.txt', cwd=f'{bat_location}',
                      stdin=PIPE, shell=True)

def new_command(self, command):
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

What I do here is I call a subprocess which is defined in the **init** to run a TerrariaServer.exe with a couple of extra commands that the server needs.

The new_command method is basically used when someone in the discord server makes a new request for a command to be executed, for example : 'noon'(changing the ingame time), 'exit'(to close the server), 'save'(save the world) etc.

To start the server I use a command called !terraria

```
@client.command()
async def terraria(ctx):
    global is_server_on
    if is_server_on:
        ctx.send("Server is already running.")
    else:
        ctx.send("Server starting!")
        run_terraria_server()
        is_server_on = True
```

All it does it checks if the server is already running, if its not run it.

But then I ran into a problem that I cannot explain. Its like the server is simultaneously running with a standard command line. Because every time I call this function :

```
@client.command()
async def terraria_commands(ctx, command):
    global is_server_on
    global proc
    if is_server_on:
        proc.new_command(command)
    else:
        ctx.send("Server is not running.")
```

So with the function new_command the user enters a command like !terraria_commands *some command* and the server should execute it. But instead I get this :

```
    'noon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     operable program or batch file.
```

WHAAAT?? Its like the server is running (which it is, I can without trouble enter it) but the commands get executed on a standard cmd. Am I not getting something here?

Here is a picture of the command prompt which the terraria server is running!

[server command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrjiq.png)

Any help is apriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have found a solution using pywinauto.

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Basically this script can control any running exe as well as running them.

So what I did was I ran terraria with a subprocess :

```
self.proc = Popen('TerrariaServer.exe -steam -lobby friends -config serverconfig.txt', cwd=f'{bat_location}',
                      shell=True)
```

Then searched for the application that was running with pywinauto :

```
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia")['TerrariaServer']
dlg.type_keys('%s\n{ENTER}' % command)
```

Since I have a laptop dedicated only to run the terraria server, I ignored the possibility that anyone would be using the PC, so I just send the command through an automated method (type_keys).